# Optimizing MySQLs ALTER TABLE

Tags: php, mysql, performance, alter

I'm running multiple SQL queries to create ~30 tables.

and especially

```
ALTER TABLE `...` MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

takes at least one second even if the table is empty. So it takes up to 80 seconds to create all my tables with PHP.

Is there any way to optimize it?

Comment: It would be way faster to define the auto-increment while table definition. Why alter at all?

Comment: Could you explain more clearly what the purpose of creating and altering tables all the time is?

Comment: I'm only creating them once, if the customer installs the product. I'm

Comment: Did you not have the `AUTO_INCREMENT` in the `CREATE TABLE` originally?